# Pandas - Group By ID, Get Percentage

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Say I have a dataframe like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['3a2b', '2a2b', '1a2b', '1a2b'],
               'label': [2, 2, 1, 0]})
```

df visualized:

```
        ID   label
        3a2b    2
        2a2b    2
        1a2b    1
        1a2b    0
```

Now I'd like to groupby ID and display the % of labels associated with that ID are of each [0, 1, 2]

Desired output visualized:

```
ID       label 0        label 1       label 2
1a2b       50%             50%           0%
2a2b       0%              0%           100%
3a2b       0%              0%           100%
```

I've tried:

```
  df.groupby(['ID']).agg({'label': 'sum'})
```

but it doesn't quite work.

The denominator for each column can be found using:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['ID']).agg({'label': 'count'})
```

which outputs:

```
ID .      label
1a2b .     2
2a2b .     1
3a2b .     1
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The question is how do I divide by the amount of instances a number shows up, not the number itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_dummies` on `label`, and groupby on `ID`, then `sum`, and apply row-wise percentage calculation.

```
In [48]: (pd.get_dummies(df['label'], prefix='label')
            .groupby(df['ID'])
            .sum()
            .apply(lambda x: x / x.sum() * 100, axis=1)
         )
Out[48]:
      label_0  label_1  label_2
ID
1a2b     50.0     50.0      0.0
2a2b      0.0      0.0    100.0
3a2b      0.0      0.0    100.0
```

Details

```
In [49]: pd.get_dummies(df['label'], prefix='label')
Out[49]:
   label_0  label_1  label_2
0      0.0      0.0      1.0
1      0.0      0.0      1.0
2      0.0      1.0      0.0
3      1.0      0.0      0.0

In [50]: pd.get_dummies(df['label'], prefix='label').groupby(df['ID']).sum()
Out[50]:
      label_0  label_1  label_2
ID
1a2b      1.0      1.0      0.0
2a2b      0.0      0.0      1.0
3a2b      0.0      0.0      1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by ID, select 'labels', count distinct values:

```
x = df.groupby(['ID'])['label'].value_counts()
```

Normalize and transform into a "wide" table:

```
(x / x.groupby(level=0).sum()).unstack().fillna(0) * 100
#label     0     1      2
#ID                      
#1a2b   50.0  50.0    0.0
#2a2b    0.0   0.0  100.0
#3a2b    0.0   0.0  100.0
```